# Creating unique surveys with SDAPS

Tags: questionnaire

I have successfully run through the tutorial for using SDAPS with a LATEX survey to generate forms with tick boxes that a participant can fill out and I can scan and extract the data. However, I cannot figure out how to generate unique surveys with a different bar code on each one. Has anyone else done this? I can just get one survey.

In the tutorial for the software, I read the following:

' If we make each printout unique using a "Questionnaire-ID" then we would need to use the "stamp" command to create the printable document. You can try this by setting the "print_questionnaire_id" option before creating the survey directory.'

I'm not sure if this "print_questionnaire_id" is in the LATEX or outside the latex when creating the PDFS...

Answer (score 2):

It is an option for the "sdaps" LaTeX document class.

That means you'd put it among your other options like this:

```
\documentclass[english, pdf, pagemark, stamp, print_questionnaire_id]{sdaps}
```